# how to split into multiple excel workbooks from a list of data frames with conditional formatting

Tags: r, export-to-excel, conditional-formatting

I have list of data frames. I need to export each data frames into separate excel workbooks with same condition formatting.

I tried with this code but can't export each data frames to separate excel workbooks.

```
for (i in 1:length(final_tables)) {
  addWorksheet(wbs, sheetName=names(final_tables[i]))
  boldRows[[i]]<-(data.frame(which(final_tables[[i]] == "total", arr.ind=TRUE)))
  ne_style<-createStyle(textDecoration = "bold")
  head_style<-createStyle(fgFill ="#99CCFF" ,border = c("top", "bottom", "left", "right"),borderStyle = "thick")
  addStyle(wbs,sheet =names(final_tables[i]), cols = 1:ncol(final_tables[[i]]), rows = boldRows[[i]][,1]+1,
       style = ne_style, gridExpand = TRUE)
  writeData(wbs, sheet=names(final_tables[i]), x=final_tables[[i]],headerStyle = head_style)
}

saveWorkbook(wbs, "iris.xlsx")
```

[image]

my task is:

1. split a data frame based on regions
2. color header background
3. draw border and color header background
4. bold the rows which contain text total
5. export each dataframe to separate Excel workbooks

Answer (score 1):

You didn’t share your dataset, so my example below uses the `penguins` dataset
from the `palmerpenguins` package.

```r
library(openxlsx)
library(palmerpenguins)
library(purrr)
```

First, we create a function that creates the workbook, adds a worksheet,
adds the data, applies the styles you specified, and stores the result as
an XLSX file.

```r
create_style_save_workbook <-
  function(data,
           sheet_name,
           bold_row_trigger_string,
           bold_row_trigger_column) {
    wb <- createWorkbook()
    
    addWorksheet(wb,
                 sheet_name)
    
    writeData(wb,
              data,
              sheet = sheet_name)
    
    bold_rows <-
      which((data[bold_row_trigger_column] == bold_row_trigger_string)) + 1
    
    addStyle(
      wb,
      sheet_name,
      createStyle(textDecoration = "bold"),
      rows = bold_rows,
      cols = 1:ncol(data),
      gridExpand = TRUE
    )
    
    head_style <-
      createStyle(
        fgFill = "#99CCFF",
        border = c("top", "bottom", "left", "right"),
        borderStyle = "thick"
      )
    
    addStyle(
      wb,
      sheet = sheet_name,
      cols = 1:ncol(data),
      rows = 1,
      style = head_style,
      gridExpand = TRUE
    )
    
    saveWorkbook(wb, paste0(sheet_name, ".xlsx"), overwrite = TRUE)
  }
```

Instead of bolding the “total” rows, in my example, I bold all rows where
the column `sex` is “female”.

We can use this function to export the whole dataset as an XLSX file:

```r
create_style_save_workbook(penguins, "penguins", "female", 7)
```

To split the dataframe and write each subset into a separate file, we can use
`split()` and `purrr::imap()`.

Instead of splitting on regions, I am splitting on the `islands` column here.

```r
split(penguins,
      penguins$island) |>
  imap(create_style_save_workbook, "female", 7)
#> $Biscoe
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $Dream
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $Torgersen
#> [1] 1
```

For your data this should work:

```r
final_tables |>
  imap(create_style_save_workbook, "total", 3)
```